# Почему не работает кастомное правило валидации изображения?

Tags: php, laravel

На сервер приходит строка в виде base64 из канваса. Создано правило для ее проверки Base64.php:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Base64 implements Rule
{

  public function passes($attribute, $value)
  {
    return base64_encode(base64_decode($value,true))===$value; 
  }
  public function message()
  {
    return 'Неверный формат изображения!';
  }
}
```

А вот это правило в ProductCreateRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'cat' => ['required'],
      'title' => ['required','max:250'],
      'price' => ['required'],
      'color'=>['max:100']
      'canvas_photo.*' => [new Base64]
    ];
}
```

Проблема в том, что фоток и канвасов несколько и некоторые могут быть пустыми и они соответственно не проходят валидацию. Как выкинуть пустые поля или как-то их указать, чтобы из-за них не срывалась проверка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так попробовать

```
'canvas_photo.*' => ['nullable',new Base64]
```